# WebView shouldOverrideUrlLoading Wont Play Video

Tags: android, video, webview, mp4

My app displays a webpage using a WebView. I want the user to be able to click on a link to a video, and the video be played in landscape mode. Where I am now, the video doesn't even play??

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.mnwv_main);     

myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
myWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);    

myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());      
myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.meanwhileinwv.com");

}     
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url) {
if (url.endsWith(".mp4")){
    Intent in = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_VIEW , Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(in);
    return true;
}
else
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
...

myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());      
myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.meanwhileinwv.com");

}     
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url) {
if (url.endsWith(".mp4")){
    Intent in = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_VIEW , Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(in);
    return true;
}
else
    return false;
}
```

with this:

```
...

myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.endsWith(".mp4")){
            Intent in = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_VIEW , Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(in);
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
        }

});      
myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.meanwhileinwv.com");

}
```