# android- any way to open chrome from the app without passing an intent? chrome scheme?

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview, url-scheme

The situation I have now is that I have an app built with webview which is pointing to my website. I never had any file for user to download on my site, so I never take care of `onDownloadStart`. here comes an issue when I recently upload a file to my site and let user to download it. Users are not able to download the file if they are inside of the app. I can however set the `downloadlistsner` but people with older version are hopeless. I then came up with an idea to send user to chrome. but throwing out an intent for chrome to catch isn't available yet in the app with older version. the only place I can make this happen is update my site. Is it possible that I can do something like `chrome://url=blahblah` and have chrome to take care of the url? or is there any better way to solve this issue?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [intent: scheme](https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/intents), and specify the Chrome activity as the target, however this will only work if the user has Chrome installed.

Also, whether this works or not depends how you implemented WebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading:

- if you didn't set a WebViewClient at all, then it's fine,
- otherwise you would need code in shouldOverrideUrlLoading that would create an Intent ([something similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8258246/2977376)).

Comment: scheme was the 1st thing I tried but looks like only browser would take care of that, webview doesn't.

Comment: i can totally set `downloadlistsner` to take care of this properly, but the situation I have now is I don't want to touch my app. All I want to change is my site cz there are still existing users with older app version. I kinda noticed this might be impossible... because there's no listener already sitting there in the app. I would be surprise if there's a way to trigger event in android without having a proper listener

Comment: @user1865027 - what I was trying to say is that if you either a) didn't set a `WebViewClient`, or b) implemented the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method in a particular way it would be possible to use the intent: scheme (it's not true this only works in Browser). The `WebViewClient` is *not* the same thing as the `DownloadListener`. Anyway, I don't have any more ideas than that.

Comment: sorry...let me correct my sentence. it is possible to setup a way to take care of scheme, but just cz my app does not have it setup first.

Comment: so seems like theres no way around now...:(